# How to write a different version of stl algorithms in c++?

Tags: c++, stl, compiler-errors

For practice, I wrote some `template` functions whose names are the same as the stl algorithms. But my code can not compile

> error: Call to < algorithm_name > is ambiguous.

I only included `using std::necessary_names;` in my code rather than `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete example that shows your problem.

Comment: They're called 'function templates' (templates of functions) not 'template functions' (functions that work on templates).

Comment: It's the C++ Standard Library, not the "STL".

Comment: @Paul - the two terms are used interchangeably, even in the C++ standard. See, for example §30.6.8/1: `The template function async ...`.

Comment: @Mankarse But they don't (shouldn't) mean the same thing, from a grammatical point of view. 'Template functions' would be a correct term if used to refer to functions used in metaprogramming.

Comment: (Also, this question really has nothing to do with the Standard Library, but can be reformed as a general question about name lookup.)

Comment: @Paul: In "template functions" when meaning "templates of functions", "template" works as an adjective. The usual term for functions used in metaprogramming is "metafunctions".

Comment: @R. Martinho That's what I was arguing, 'template functions' is the correct term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you have `using`, [the "used" name takes precedence](http://codepad.org/5MfEeLkr):

```
namespace N { int x = 0; }
int x = 1;

int main() {
   using N::x;
   cout << x;
}

// Output: 0
```

However, Argument-Dependent Lookup [can mess this up](http://codepad.org/jBhl14Vg):

```
namespace N {
   struct T {};
   void f(T) {}
}

namespace M {
    void f(N::T) {}
}

int main() {
   using M::f;
   N::T o;
   f(o);       // <--- error: call of overloaded 'f(N::T&)' is ambiguous
}
```

So, if you are having trouble, [qualify your own namespace (in this example, `M`) explicitly](http://codepad.org/0qAcOFTx):

```
namespace N {
   struct T {};
   void f(T)     { cout << "N::f"; }
}

namespace M {
    void f(N::T) { cout << "M::f"; }
}

int main() {
   using M::f;
   N::T o;
   M::f(o);    // <--- Output: "M::f"
}
```

In a somewhat bizarre twist, [you can also use parentheses to prevent ADL](http://codepad.org/A3sPjrcw):

```
namespace N {
   struct T {};
   void f(T)     { cout << "N::f"; }
}

namespace M {
    void f(N::T) { cout << "M::f"; }
}

int main() {
   using M::f;
   N::T o;
   (f)(o);     // <--- Output: "M::f"
}
```

---

#### Explanation

> `[n3290: 3.4.1/1]:` *[re: unqualified name lookup]* In all the cases
>   listed in 3.4.1, **the scopes are searched for a declaration in the
>   order listed in each of the respective categories; name lookup ends
>   as soon as a declaration is found for the name**. If no declaration is
>   found, the program is ill-formed.
>
> `[n3290: 3.4.1/2]:` *[i.e. first priority]* The declarations from the
>   namespace nominated by a *using-directive* become visible in a namespace
>   enclosing the *using-directive*; see 7.3.4. For the purpose of the
>   unqualified name lookup rules described in 3.4.1, the declarations
>   from the namespace nominated by the *using-directive* are considered
>   members of that enclosing namespace.
>
> `[n3290: 3.4.2/1]:` *[re: argument-dependent lookup]* When the *postfix-expression* in a function call
>   (5.2.2) is an *unqualified-id*, **other namespaces not considered during
>   the usual unqualified lookup** (3.4.1) **may be searched**, and in those
>   namespaces, namespace-scope friend function declarations (11.3) not
>   otherwise visible may be found. These modifications to the search
>   depend on the types of the arguments (and for template template
>   arguments, the namespace of the template argument).

i.e. Normal lookup stops at the name that you brought into scope with `using`, but when ADL comes into play, other names are also added to the candidate set, causing an ambiguity between two names.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to declare your own version in a `namespace`; so that such problem would not occur.

```
namespace MySTL
{
  template<typename T, ... > // ... means other template params
  class vector;

  template<typename T, ... >
  class queue;
...
}
```

now you can do,

```
using std::vector;
```

which will not collide with `MySTL::vector`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `MyTL` rather? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you are hitting a problem with Argument Dependent Lookup. When you pass a type that is defined within a namespace to an unqualified function, the namespaces of all the arguments are implicitly added to the lookup set, and that might cause collisions. You can try to qualify your own algorithm calls to inhibit ADL from kicking in.

```
namespace n {
   struct test {};
   void foo( test const & ) {}
};
int main() {
   n::test t;
   foo( t );    // Will find n::foo as the argument belongs to n namespace
}
```